# Deletion closure-duplicate check bug

Tags: bug, vote-to-delete

*[Note, some of the links below can only be accessed by those with Diamond on Math.SE]*

When voting to delete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312327/fracx2x-yy2z-x-fracy2y-zz2xy-fracz2z-xx2yz-geq#question) from Math.SE, I encountered something new: the system makes a reverse check to make sure that there are no questions "linked to it". I applaud this new system which helps moderators avoid leaving dangling questions marked as a duplicate of a question that no longer exists.

However, I think there is a small bug in the algorithm doing the check. More precisely, I saw a dialog box which stated to the effect of:

> The following two questions are marked as duplicates of this one, are you sure you want to proceed?

One of them is indeed a duplicate posted by the same user, and the algorithm worked well. 
The other is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/313262/revisions). From the revision history we see that the question is not closed as a duplicate of the first link above. But for some reason the code that runs the check when I voted to delete the first link *thinks* that it is closed as a duplicate.

It is possible that I am missing something, can someone explain?